# Add/Remove input subfields in form with JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a HTML form with Bootstrap v1.5.3, the code contains 3 select inputs, the first select has an "Add Group" and "Delete Group" button that when you click on it, adds a new group with the same 3 selects or deletes the added groups, however my current problem is in the handling of the subgroups, I need that when you click on "Add SubGroup", it adds only the 2 selects that are on the same line of the "Add SubGroup" button within the Group to which they belong. Currently if you click on "Add SubGroup" it adds them all in the initial Group, sometimes I have managed to do it in the new groups, however when I add a subgroup it adds me in the "X" groups that I have, I am sure that it is due to the variable "subGroupWrap" being static, it does not detect which one to delete and in the group to which it corresponds, however I have not managed yet a way that it detects these corresponding wraps.

```js
var groupCounter = 0;

function addGroup(){
    groupCounter += 1;

    var groupWrap = document.querySelector('.group-wrapper');
    var groupHTML = `
    <div class="group-wrapper${groupCounter} my-3 row">
        <div class="col-12">
        <select
            class="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
            name="inputOne"
        >
            <option selected>Input One</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="subgroup-wrapper my-3 row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <select
            class="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
            name="inputOne"
            >
            <option selected>Input One</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <select
            class="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
            name="inputOne"
            >
            <option selected>Input One</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary addGroup" onclick="addSubGroup()">Add SubGroup</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;

    groupWrap.innerHTML+=groupHTML;
}

function addSubGroup(){
    var subGroupWrap = document.querySelector('.subgroup-wrapper');
    var subGroupHTML = `
    <div class="subgroup-wrapper my-3 row">
    <div class="col-5">
        <select
        class="form-select"
        aria-label="Default select example"
        name="inputOne"
        >
        <option selected>Input One</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <select
        class="form-select"
        aria-label="Default select example"
        name="inputOne"
        >
        <option selected>Input One</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger addGroup" onclick="removeSubGroup()">Remove SubGroup</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    `;

    subGroupWrap.innerHTML+=subGroupHTML;
}

function removeGroup(){
    if(groupCounter >= 1){
        var  groupWrap = document.querySelector(`.group-wrapper${groupCounter}`);
        groupWrap.remove();
        groupCounter -= 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Form</title>
    <!--CSS Bootstrap v5.1.3-->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="group-wrapper my-3 row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <select
              class="form-select"
              aria-label="Default select example"
              name="inputOne"
            >
              <option selected>Input One</option>
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
              <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary addGroup" onclick="addGroup()">Add Group</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger removeGroup" onclick="removeGroup()">Remove Group</button>
          </div>
          <div class="subgroup-wrapper my-3 row">
            <div class="col-5">
              <select
                class="form-select"
                aria-label="Default select example"
                name="inputOne"
              >
                <option selected>Input One</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
              <select
                class="form-select"
                aria-label="Default select example"
                name="inputOne"
              >
                <option selected>Input One</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary addGroup" onclick="addSubGroup()">Add SubGroup</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="group.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="subgroup.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function `removeSubGroup()` is not defined. Is this your error or did you forget to add the function?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't specify that part, that's the next step, for the moment I only need that it add subgroups in the specific group but if some one can help me in both things because I think that "removeSubGroup()" in the future will be a headache too